# Using Azure DevOps REST API to Create or Trigger a Release with build artifacts from another Team Project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I was able to trigger a release pipeline using PowerShell script and REST API. But what I am trying now is to to trigger a release (or even create a release) in a team project using artifacts from build that exists in different team project. (I am aware that this is possible to do in GUI of azure devops)

Is there a way to do this ? to pass artifacts from another project build in the json body?

```
$ReleaseUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.0"
$body= @"
{
    "variables": {AzureVM: {value: "11.6.101"}, environment: {value: "dev"}},
    "definitionId": 1,
    "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "_myrepo",
      "instanceReference": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
"@
```

Comment: I am not sure about the answer, but as long as you use the same virtual machine (build) for both projects, you can try to add the other project artifact alias and check the result if this will work.

Comment: For 'triggering a release' - I did try and it gave me an error "Artifact source with alias _mybuild could not be found in the existing release" . However if I link the artifact manually to the release definition and then execute the script , it seems to take the artifact alias. In case of 'creating new release' - i assume this may not work , since artifact cannot be pre-defined. Looking for a way to do that without pre-defining the artifact in the release definition